# Passing property list as strongly typed parameters

Tags: c#

I have this method which extracts the property name from an expresssion:

```
private static string GetPropertyName<TObj, TProp>(Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>> prop)
{
    var expression = prop.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (expression != null)
    {
        var property = expression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        if (property != null)
        {
            return property.Name;
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

So later I can use it like this:

```
GetPropertyName((User u) => u.Surname); //Returns "Surname"
```

I would like to be able to pass a collection of properties instead one by one. Just to be clear, the properties could be of different types.

Comment: Are you able to take advantage of the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` instead and cut this code out altogether? Or, in C# 6 the new `nameof` keyword.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth `CallerMemberName` is not useful if you want to do multiple calls in one. `nameof` indeed is.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, not useful for this case, but I mention it as well just to highlight it - it isn't always known about.

Comment: True. Often it is very useful indeed.

Comment: if you dont want to use C#6.0 you will the code you have written and use the `param` and loop through in your method. and it will return the name of the properties.  list of string

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it should be C# 5 code unfortunately. When I loop it this is null: var expression = prop.Body as MemberExpression; because TProp would be an object type.

Comment: If your code is right my code is right. The error is on another place ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am completely agree with @Patrick and its preferred way over mine.

but if you say you are not using the C#6.0 and then you can use the code you have written.  I just use the `param`, `yield return` and one `foreach` loop

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyName<TObj, TProp>(params Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>>[] propCollection)
    {

        foreach (var prop in propCollection)
        {

            var expression = prop.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (expression != null)
            {
                var property = expression.Member as PropertyInfo;

                if (property != null)
                {
                    yield return property.Name;
                }
            }
            yield return string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**

First One ask you to specific the type of the object again and again mean you have to provide the full length expression again.

Try the below it will ask you to specify the property as much as you want in one Expression only.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertiesName<TObj, TProp>(Expression<Func<TObj, TProp[]>> prop)
{
    var array = (prop.Body as NewArrayExpression);
    var exp = array == null ? null : array.Expressions;

    if (exp != null)
    {
        //var expArr = (prop.Body as NewArrayExpression).Expressions;

        foreach (var oneProp in exp)
        {
            Expression onePropExp;
            if (oneProp.GetType() == typeof (UnaryExpression))
            {
                onePropExp = (oneProp as UnaryExpression).Operand;
            }
            else
            {
                onePropExp = oneProp;
            }
            var property = (onePropExp as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;

            if (property != null)
            {
                yield return property.Name;
            }
            yield return string.Empty;
        }

    }
    yield return string.Empty;
}
```

You can call it like -

```
var propNames = GetPropertiesName((AllSubsTransAndDevices d) => new[]
{
    d.CurrentDriverId,
    d.GPSDevicesId,
    d.TransporterId
});
```

Comment: @osotorrio check the udpate

Answer (score 1):

It might be me, but I think you don't need to do this the hard way. You can simply use the C# 6 `nameof` keyword. This assumes you can use C# 6 of course.

```
string name = nameof(u.Surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Usage: `string[] props = GetPropertiesName((MainWindow m) => m.Lalala, (MainWindow m) => m.Lalala);`

```
private static string[] GetPropertiesName<TObj, TProp>(params Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>>[] prop)
{
    List<string> ret = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in prop)
        ret.Add(GetPropertyName(item));
    return ret.ToArray();
}
private static string GetPropertyName<TObj, TProp>(Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>> prop)
{
    var expression = prop.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (expression != null)
    {
        var property = expression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        if (property != null)
        {
            return property.Name;
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: When I try this out I get: 

The type arguments for method 'SqlQueryString.Core.StringExtensions.GetPropertiesName<TObj,TProp>(string, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TObj,TProp>>[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.