# Combining multiple expressions trees

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm getting the following error

> The parameter 'p' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities
>   query expression.

I understand the problem (same instance of `ParameterExpression` should be used with all the expressions in the tree) and have attempted to use solutions I've found online but with no luck.

This is my method

```
private void SeedEntity<TEntity>(DatabaseContext context, ref TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] identifierExpressions) where TEntity : class
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> allExpresions = null;

    var parameters = identifierExpressions.SelectMany(x => x.Parameters).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(p => p.First()).ToList();

    foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> identifierExpression in identifierExpressions)
    {
        Func<TEntity, object> vv = identifierExpression.Compile();
        object constant = vv(entity);

        ConstantExpression constExp = Expression.Constant(constant, typeof(object));
        BinaryExpression equalExpression1 = Expression.Equal(identifierExpression.Body, constExp);
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> equalExpression2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equalExpression1, parameters);

        if (allExpresions == null)
        {
            allExpresions = equalExpression2;
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryExpression bin = Expression.And(allExpresions.Body, equalExpression2.Body);
            allExpresions = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(bin, parameters);
        }
    }

    TEntity existingEntity = null;
    if (allExpresions != null)
    {
        existingEntity = context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(allExpresions);
    }

    if (existingEntity == null)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        entity = existingEntity;
    }
}
```

It generates an expression for the lookup of an entity based on a number of properties.

It works fine for a single expression, the error only occurs when passing in multiple.

Called like this:

```
SeedEntity(context, ref e, p=> p.Name);//Works
SeedEntity(context, ref e, p=> p.Name, p=> p.Age);//Fails
```

It generates something similar to me performing the following:

```
context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name == e.Name && p.Age == e.Age);
```

Replacing e.Name && e.Age with a `ConstantExpression`

You can see in the method above I grab all of the unique params and store them in `parameters` at the top, then use the same variable throughout.This is the start, but then I need to replace the instances of the parameter in each of the `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` passed in as the `params` array, this is where I'm failing.

I've tried enumerate the expressions and use the `.Update()` method passing in the params

I also tried a solution using the `ExpressionVisitor`

```
public class ExpressionSubstitute : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public readonly Expression from, to;
    public ExpressionSubstitute(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == from) return to;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static class ExpressionSubstituteExtentions
{
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturnType>> RewireLambdaExpression<TEntity, TReturnType>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturnType>> expression, ParameterExpression newLambdaParameter)
    {
        var newExp = new ExpressionSubstitute(expression.Parameters.Single(), newLambdaParameter).Visit(expression);
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturnType>>)newExp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick thought, have you tried using a different letter for the second parameter? (ie p=> p.Name, f=> f.Age)

Comment: Thanks for the input, this would never work, as you only have one parameter but your passing in two. It'll throw Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda

Comment: Instead of combining the queries, why not apply them successively? `results = /*Full set*/; foreach(expression) {results = results.Where(expression)}` ? As EF uses `IQueryable`, the framework will defer execution until needed, then combine all predicates into a single query for SQL.

Comment: are you trying to pass multiple property to one method?? check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630945/passing-property-list-as-strongly-typed-parameters/33631401#33631401 update part.

Comment: @Basic Thanks for the idea, this was more of a learning curve than trying to find the easier solution. Thanks

Comment: @StevenYates I once wrote "And" and "Or" predicate combiners (when I still didn't quite get L2E). I've since done a LinqToElasticsearch provider for the hell of it, so I definitely understand where you're coming from. Just wanted to make sure you were going 'round the long way intentionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close. I don't see the point of your `parameters` variable. Grouping them by name is a mistake. Why not just pass the parameters from the expression? Then visit if necessary. Your visitor code is fine.

```
    private static void SeedEntity<TEntity>(DbContext context, ref TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] identifierExpressions) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> allExpresions = null;

        foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> identifierExpression in identifierExpressions)
        {
            Func<TEntity, object> vv = identifierExpression.Compile();
            object constant = vv(entity);

            ConstantExpression constExp = Expression.Constant(constant, typeof(object));
            BinaryExpression equalExpression1 = Expression.Equal(identifierExpression.Body, constExp);
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> equalExpression2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equalExpression1, identifierExpression.Parameters);

            if (allExpresions == null)
            {
                allExpresions = equalExpression2;
            }
            else
            {
                var visitor = new ExpressionSubstitute(allExpresions.Parameters[0], identifierExpression.Parameters[0]);
                var modifiedAll = (Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>)visitor.Visit(allExpresions);
                BinaryExpression bin = Expression.And(modifiedAll.Body, equalExpression2.Body);
                allExpresions = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(bin, identifierExpression.Parameters);
            }
        }

        TEntity existingEntity = null;
        if (allExpresions != null)
        {
            existingEntity = context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(allExpresions);
        }

        if (existingEntity == null)
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entity = existingEntity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I grabbed the unique permissions thinking that I could reuse that instance by replacing the parameters (not in the above example). You solution works, thank you very much. I see where I went wrong now